# drawImage on a canvas with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have built an image up on a canvas with drawImage using several pieces.

I now want to try either load them in 1 by 1, or, attempt animate them or modify the size of the pieces used to make up the full image after they have initially loaded.

I am having trouble getting them to work with a `setTimeout` function, is this even a suitable method? or is there a better way?

Here is my original working canvas built with several image pieces:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyaMOK

Here is my attempt loading them in 1 by 1 and the `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img, piece.sx, piece.sy, piece.sWidth, piece.sHeight, piece.x, piece.y, piece.w, piece.h);
},100*tileCount);
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaWzgJ

It seems to just load 1 "piece" in the bottom right corner, and none of the others, though this method seems to work fine outside the `setTimeout`.

Can anyone suggest a workable solution?

Comment: `setTimeout` waits for the duration specified in the 2nd argument then calls the `callback` function _once_. I think you are looking for `setInterval` .

Comment: I am aware of the difference, I only want to do this once per loop. otherwise i'm creating infinite loops on many 'pieces'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

making function within a function = bad. moved the `setTimeout` function outside of the for loop and passed the variables to it from within, updated working codepen is here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaWzgJ

Comment: I'm surprised this worked, not sure why. Do you have any idea? In the previous example I noticed that every `piece.something` value was remaining the same for every iteration. So I was wondering if something else was wrong, in that, the values of `piece.something` are not getting updated for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and modified it by adding `console.log` before the `setTimeout` function and within the `callback` of the `setTimeout` function.

The result was that the loops were working as expected. The `piece` object was getting updated for every iteration.

However, the `setTimeout` functions were called only after the entire loop was exhausted, and to my surprise, taken the same values for `piece` object.

The reason why it behaved like this, according to me, is thus:

1. `setTimeout` function only registers the `callback` function (to be executed later) but does not block the loop (it is asynchronous).
2. Therefore, the loop continues without executing any of the callbacks within `setTimeout` and `piece` gets updated through out.
3. When the loop is exhausted, the `callback` functions start executing. **However**, all the callbacks are referring to the same `piece` object (due to [`hoisting`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) and because javascipt is not block-scoped), hence they all get the same value.
4. Conclusion: all the image pieces get correctly outputted, *but they get outputted at the same place, one on-top of another*.

**Why putting `setTimeout` in another function works:**

Putting `setTimeout` in another function works because calling the new function creates a new scope with its own `piece` object, i.e., it is no longer sharing from the same global `piece` object.